# Why does HttpClient.PostAsync buffer response?

Tags: c#, httpclient

Recently I encountered performance issues when using HttpClients.PostAsync on .Net 4.5.1. Originally server (Owin + WebApi) was buffering response before sending. This was causing huge memory usage overhead (serialized response size is > 1Gb). After I turned on response streaming on the server client literally stopped working. It turned out that reason was buffer re-allocation on the client when reading response from server. I checked HttpClient implementation and found this interesting part in `HttpClient.SendAsync` method:

```
if (result.Content == null || completionOption == HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
{
    this.SetTaskCompleted(request, linkedCts, tcs, result);
}
else
{
    this.StartContentBuffering(request, linkedCts, tcs, result);
}
```

So when `completionOption` is not `ResponseHeadersRead` response is always buffered. According to [SendAsync documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) implementation of SendAsync is consistent with the intent.

Now, as `PostAsync` is implemented sending `ResponseContentRead`, response stream is  always buffered on POSTs. So question is why does PostAsync have to wait (and buffer) for whole response to arrive before processing continues?

Comment: Hi @koruyucu, I want to use HttpClient for calling a SOAP web service, therefore, I won't use `PostAsync` for sending the request, I'm wondering to know does it work well for you to using `SendAsync` instead? I'm asking this because HttpClient has changed since 2015. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

There's the obvious part - if you don't specify `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`, the `Task` will only complete when the whole response is read; you have to store the response data *somewhere* in the meantime.

Why doesn't `PostAsync` allow you to specify `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`? Probably because it's not really all that useful, most of the time. `POST` is for posting data, not for retrieving it - that's `GET`'s job. `HttpClient` was designed around WebAPIs and "REST" services, with proper use of HTTP verbs.

If you need to use `POST` to retrieve such large amounts of data, you have two basic options:

- Use `SendAsync`
- Don't use `HttpClient` (`HttpWebRequest` is a bit more complicated, but gives you way more control)

Comment: I have to use POST because my request object 'does not fit' in GET method. Anyway I changed implementation to explicit call to SendAsync

Comment: @koruyucu Yeah, that can be tricky. The usual way to solve this REST-fully would be to use e.g. `PUT` to push your request object to the server, which would return you an URL to `GET` to retrieve the response. But it will probably create more trouble than it solves :D

Comment: @Luaan because it would solve *nothing*, to be clear :)

Comment: It would pull certain timeouts out of the question, but not the initial request payload, nor the final response payload.