# Periodically read from Task<Stream> returned from Http PostAsync response content

Tags: c#, http, async-await

I have an application where after posting a file to a server, the server periodically returns messages to the client application about the upgrade process in it's response.

I used to have code that looks something like

```
using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while(!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var str = streamReader.ReadLine();
                // Do something with str
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After updating my code to utilize the `HttpClient` class I am struggling to find a method that will do the same as the code above.

```
var response = client.PostAsync(uploadUrl, content).Result;

var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);

// Superfluous due to the fact we are already at end of stream
while(!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
    var str = streamReader.ReadLine();
    // Do something with str
}
```

If I try something like the above then we wait until the entire stream has been populate before returning it all in one go due to the use of the `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result` call. This is not suitable as I wish to display the information in real time when it is returned from the server.

Is it possible to periodically read from the stream as is done in the above example when we have an `Task<Stream>` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `ReadAsStreamAsync()` only returns after all content is received is because `PostAsync()` internally uses `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead`. What you want is `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

Some methods on `HttpClient` have an overload that accepts `HttpCompletionOption`, which allows you to override the default. Unfortunately for you, `PostAsync()` does not. Apparently, this is because [responses to POST requests are not supposed to be long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30475576/41071).

But you can still do what you want by using the general `SendAsync()` method:

```
var response = client.SendAsync(
    new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uploadUrl) { Content = content },
    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
```